# grey screen in testflight

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

I worked my webview project with flutter

It's totally worked in xCode or androidStudio, But it didn't work and show just grey screen in testflight.

There are no crush code exists.

Of course my inquiry is so ambiguous but I'm just start study flutter

Therefore, I hope you understand me generously.

here is my error code

## main.dart

```dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (token == null) {
      await getToken();
  }
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  showNotification(message);
}

var token;

Future<void> getToken() async {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  if(Platform.isAndroid){
    token = await messaging.getToken();
  } else {
    token = await messaging.getAPNSToken();
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  await getToken();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ],
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  Future<void> _initApp() async {
    final status = await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
    print('traking status $status');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'JW_WebApp',
            theme: ThemeData(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
              useMaterial3: true,
            ),
            home: IndexPage(
              title: 'JW_WebApp',
              token: token,
              backgroundHandler: firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

## index_page.dart

```dart
class IndexPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndexPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.token,
      required this.backgroundHandler});
  final String title;
  final String token;
  final Future<void> Function(RemoteMessage) backgroundHandler;
  @override
  State<IndexPage> createState() => _IndexPageState();
}

class _IndexPageState extends State<IndexPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      showNotification(message);
    });
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(widget.backgroundHandler);
    notifications
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    LocalNotification.initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  GoRouter get _router => GoRouter(
        initialLocation: '/',
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/',
            builder: (_, state) => HomeScreen(
              token: widget.token,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    LocalNotification.requestPermission();
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'NotoSans',
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

## local_notification.dart

```
class LocalNotification {
  LocalNotification._();

  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static initialize() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('favicon');

    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIos =
        const DarwinInitializationSettings(
            requestAlertPermission: true,
            requestBadgePermission: true,
            requestSoundPermission: true);
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIos,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static requestPermission() async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
  }
}
```

- again I hope you understand me generously Thank you

Comment: Is there any piece of code that u doubt it causes your error?